# C# -> Repeaters and Displaying them with Loops through Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, repeater

My question is part curiosity and part help, so bear with me.

My previous question had to do with passing text files as an argument to a function, which I managed to figure out with help, so thank you to all who helped previously.

So, consider this code bit:

```
protected bool FindWordInFile(StreamReader wordlist, string word_to_find) 
{
    // Read the first line.
    string line = wordlist.ReadLine();

    while (line != null)
    {
       if(line.Contains(word_to_find))
       {
           return true;
        }

       // Read the next line.
       line = wordlist.ReadLine();
     }

     return false;
 }
```

What happens with this particular function if you call in it the following way:

```
temp_sentence_string = post_words[i]; //Takes the first string in the array FROM the array and binds it to a temporary string variable
WordCount.Text = WordCount.Text + " ||| " + temp_sentence_string;
word_count = temp_sentence_string.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); 


for (int word_pos = 0; word_pos < word_count.Length; word_pos++)
{                            
      bool WhatEver = FindWordInFile(goodwords_string, word_count[word_pos]);
      if (WhatEver == true)
      {
           WordTest.Text = WordTest.Text + "{" + WhatEver + "} ";
      }

      WordTest.Text = WordTest.Text + "{" + WhatEver + "}";
}
```

AND:

The string passed is "good times are good" and the text file has the word "good" in it is this:

```
good{True}times{False}are{False}good{False}
```

Pretty strange. It looks like what happened is that:
 1. The sentence "good times are good" got put into an array, split by the detection of a space. This happened correctly.
 2. The first array element, "good" was compared against the text file and returned True. So that worked.
 3. It then went to the next word "times", compared it, came up False.
 4. Went to the next word "are", compared it, came up False.
 5. THEN it got to the final word, "good", BUT it evaluated to False. This should NOT have happened.

So, my question is - what happened? It looks like the function of FindWordInFile was perhaps not coded right on my end, and somehow it kept returning False even though the word "good" was in the text file.

**Second Part: Repeaters in ASP.NET and C#**

So I have a repeater object bound to an array that is INSIDE a for loop. This particular algorithm takes an array of sentences and then breaks them down into a temp array of words. The temp array of words is bound to the Repeater.

But what happens is, let's say I have two sentences to do stuff to...

And so it's inside a loop. It does the stuff to the first array of words, and then does it to the second array of words, but what happens in the displaying the contents of the array, it only shows the contents of the LAST array that was generated and populated. Even though it's in the for loop, my expectation was that it would show all the word arrays, one after the other. But it only shows the last one. So if there's 5 sentences to break up, it only shows the 5th sentence that was populated by words.

Any ideas why?

```
for (int i = 0; i < num_sentences; i++) //num_sentences is an int that counted the number of elements in the array of sentences that was populated before. It populates the array by splitting based on punctuation.
{
    temp_sentence_string = post_words[i]; //Takes the first string in the array FROM the sentence array and binds it to a temporary string variable
    WordCount.Text = WordCount.Text + " ||| " + temp_sentence_string;
    word_count = temp_sentence_string.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); //create a word count array with one word as a singular element in the array

    //We have the Word Count Array now. We can go through it with a loop, right?

    for (int j = 0; j < word_count.Length; j++)
    {
        Boolean FoundIt = File
         .ReadLines(@"c:\wordfilelib\goodwords.txt")               // <- Your file name
             .Any(line => line.Contains(word_count[j]));

        WordTest.Text = WordTest.Text + FoundIt + "(" + word_count[j] + ")";
    }

    Repeater2.DataSource = word_count;
    Repeater2.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First Part**

You are passing a StreamReader into the Find function. A StreamReader must be reset in order to be used multiple times. Test with the following sentence and you will see the result.

```
"good good good good"
```

you will get

```
good{true}good{false}good{false}good{false}
```

I would suggest reading the file into an array only one time and then do your processing over the array.

```
using System.Linq
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class WordFinder
{
    private static bool FindWordInLines(string word_to_find, string[] lines)
    {
        foreach(var line in lines)
        {
             if(line.Contains(word_to_find)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }  

    public string SearchForWordsInFile(string path, string sentence)
    {
         // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx
         var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);

         var words = sentence.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); 

         var result = string.Empty;
         foreach(var word in words)
         {
             var found = FindWordInLines(word, lines);
             // {{ in string.Format outputs {
             // }} in string.Format outputs }
             // {0} says use first parameter's ToString() method
             result += string.Format("{{{0}}}", found);
         }
         return result;
    }
}
```

**Second Part:**

If you bind it in the for loop like that it will only bind to the last result. If you accumulate the results in the outer loop you can pass the accumulated results to the repeater and bind outside the loop.

I created a sample loop class below that has two loops. The "resultList" is the variable that accumulates the results.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class LoopExample
{
     public void RunLoopExample()
     {
          var outerList = new string[]{"the", "quick", "brown", "fox"};
          var innerList = new string[]{"jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"};
          // define the resultList variable outside the outer loop
          var resultList = new List<string>();
          for(int outerIndex = 0; outerIndex < outerList.Length; outerIndex ++)
          {
              var outerValue = outerList[outerIndex];
              for(int innerIndex = 0; innerIndex < innerList.Length; innerIndex++)
              {
                  var innerValue = innerList[innerIndex];
                  resultList.Add(string.Format("{0}->{1}; ", outerValue, innerValue));
              }
          }
          // use the resultList variable outside the outer loop
          foreach(var result in resultList )
          {
              Console.WriteLine(result);
          }
     }
}
```

In your example, you would set the dataSource to the resultList

```
Repeater2.DataSource = resultList;
Repeater2.DataBind();
```

Comment: Yes, I have thought of that. The issue/error Visual Studio is telling me is when I put: Repeater2.DataSource = word_count; outside that loop, it tells me it's unassigned.

Comment: It needs to be defined outside the scope of the outer loop in order to be used.

Comment: I have tried that. I get an error message that says:

"Use of unassigned local variable word_count."

The initialization of word_count happens outside the loop, too, before it starts. Inside the loop, it gets bound to a string that is split by spaces, which then populates the array. I'm still confused. Gah. :P

Comment: Ah, ok I think I see a way of doing this. Thank you. :)

Comment: Ugh. Still not working. I tried making a new array that would load up elements with an array as it goes through the loop, but I am having difficulties binding it right with syntax and I am sick of seeing that damn error about using an unassigned variable or can't convert types. Grr.

Comment: I added an example that processes the file as an array. I also added an example for defining an accumulator variable outside the scope of the outer array so that you can use it after exiting the loops.